# Create split option in blackjack (java)

Tags: java, collections

I am currently creating a Java implementation of black jack that is not allowed to use `java.util.Collections`.

I am having trouble creating a split option in the game.

The split option, for anyone not familiar with blackjack (or 21), means that if the dealer hands the player two cards that are the same, the player can choose to split them into two separate hands.

I have the code showing the `Deal` method & the `Hit` method; I do not know how to implement the split method correctly.

Here's the `Deal()` method:

```
public static void Deal()
   {
          String choice = "#";

          //Player Goes First, play until Player or Dealer reaches 21,
          //Busts or both Player and Dealer decide to STAY
          while(choice.charAt(0) != '2' &&
                DealerTot < 21 &&
                PlayerTot < 21 &&
                PlayerStay == false
                )
          {
              System.out.println("Dealers asks " + PlayerN + ", Do you want a HIT or will you STAY?");
              System.out.println("(1)Hit\n(2)Stay\n(3)Split\n(4)Quit");
              choice = in.nextLine();

              switch(choice.charAt(0))
              {
                  case '1' : System.out.println(PlayerN + " requests a HIT.\n");
                             Hit(PLAYER);
                             break;
                  case '2' : System.out.println(PlayerN + " decides to STAY.\n");
                             PlayerStay = true;
                             ShowHand(PLAYER);
                             break;
                  case '3' ://SPLIT METHOD INCOMPLETE
                      /////toDo
                      ShowHand(PLAYER);
                      break;
                  case '4' : break;
                  default : System.out.println("Invalid input!");
                            choice = "INVALIDINPUT";
                            break;
              }
              //char ;
              //If invalid input skip Dealer events and go back to player
              if(!choice.equals("INVALIDINPUT"))
              {
                   //Dealer Only Draws if Player Not Busted
                   if(PlayerTot < 21)
                   {
                        if(DealerTot < HouseLimit)
                        {
                            System.out.println("The Dealer decides to take a card.");
                            Hit(DEALER);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("The Dealer decides to STAY.");
                            DealerStay = true;
                            ShowHand(DEALER);
                        }

                   }//close if for Player Not Busted

              }//close if for invalid choice

          }//close while true loop

   }//close function
```

Here's the `Hit()` method:

```
   public static void Hit(int ANYONE)
   {
          DRAW(ANYONE);

          if(ANYONE == PLAYER)
          {
             if(PlayerTot > 21)
             {
                for(int x = 0; x < MaximumHSize; x++)
                {
                   if(PlayersHand[x]!= null)
                   {
                       if(PlayersHand[x].GetCard() == ACE)
                       {
                            System.out.print("\n     " 
                            + PlayerN + 
                            ", You have over 21 points in your Hand!However, an ACE was found!\n"
                            + "    This Ace now represents One point as opposed to Eleven!\n");
                            PlayersHand[x].SetPointVal(1);
                            break; //If Players hand reaches above the total allowed points (21) computer will convert the ACE to 1 instead of 11.
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   { break; }
                }//close for loop

                //Recount Point values of cards after converting ACE
                //Alternatively, you could just subtract 10 from PlayerTotal
                //and set its point value to 1 without looping through the arrays above/below
                PlayerTot = 0;
                for(int x = 0; x < MaximumHSize; x++)
                {
                     if(PlayersHand[x]!= null)
                     {
                         PlayerTot = PlayerTot+ PlayersHand[x].GetPointVal();
                     }
                     else { break; }
                }

             }//close if PlayerTotal

          }//close if WHOEVER == PLAYER

          //Then must be Dealer
          else
          {
             if(DealerTot > 21)
             {
                for(int x = 0; x < MaximumHSize; x++)
                {
                   if(DealersHand[x]!= null)
                   {
                       if(DealersHand[x].GetCard() == ACE)
                       {
                            System.out.print(
                            "\n     Dealer's HAND is over 21 but an ACE was found.\n"
                            + "     We'll convert the ACE from 11 points to 1 point!\n");
                            DealersHand[x].SetPointVal(1);
                            break; //Set points of only 1 ACE to 1
                       }

                   }
                   else
                   { break; }
                }//close for loop
                //Recount Point values of cards after converting ACE
                //and set its point value to 1 without looping through the arrays above/below
                DealerTot = 0;

                for(int x = 0; x < MaximumHSize; x++)
                {
                     if(DealersHand[x]!= null)
                     {
                         DealerTot = DealerTot + DealersHand[x].GetPointVal();
                     }
                     else { break; }
                }
             }
          }

          ShowHand(ANYONE);
```

Comment: hmm, also you rather to narrow down code & show just relevant stuff

Comment: Well at a high level you need a class that represents a `hand` which each split operations would produce hands + 1 that are played by the same person. As coded above you pretty much have a 1-1 relationship between player and hand.

Comment: @Coffee Hahaha Sorry, we are not allowed use collections class i.e. List's etc. Just wanted to point it out!

Haha my problem is I have had zero success with creating a split option in the game, I thought showing one of my methods (HIT) for the game would give insight into doing something similar for the split. Seems I was wrong! :(

Comment: @JeffWard Hi Jeff thanks for helping. My problem is I have created a Giant God class and I am having trouble breaking it into separate classes such as 'hand' etc. I am rather new to java and feeling useless.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to create objects that represent the hand. Here is an off the cuff example:

```
public interface IBlackJackHand {
    public int total();
    public void stay();
    int hit(Card card); // returns hand total
    public IBlackJackHand split(); // Essentially produces two hands
}
```

Then you would have an implementation that validates a hand can be split and returns a new hand as a result leaving the original hand with the one card

```
@Override
public BlackJackHand split() {
    // Check if hand can be split... (i.e. two cards same value)
    total = total / 2;

    IBlackJackHand splitHand = new BlackJackHand(new Card(total));
    splitHand.hit(); // Add a card to the splitHand
    hit(); // add new card to the current hand
    return splitHand;
}
```